# Disable dropdown item based on selection done on other dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am working with three dropdown selects with same options. I want to disable an item if that item is selected in other dropdown. I have JQuery code working for two dropdown box. i.e. if I am selecting one item its disabled in other dropdown. But I am having trouble doing it for three dropdown. If I select one item in first that item is disabled in two and three but when I select second dropdown, third dropdown only disables second dropdown selection. 
I am new to jquery and AJAX. 
PLease guide me.
Appreciate your help.

```
 <select id="select1" name="phoneusescategories">
                          <option value="" selected="selected">top-1 use </option>
                          <option value="1"> Games</option>
                          <option value="2"> Productivity</option>
                          <option value="3"> News</option>
                          <option value="4"> Shopping & services</option>
                          <option value="5"> Music</option>
                          <option value="6"> Social Networking</option>
                          <option value="7"> Browser</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="select2" name="phoneusescategories">
                          <option value="" selected="selected">top-2 use </option>
                          <option value="1"> Games</option>
                          <option value="2"> Productivity</option>
                          <option value="3"> News</option>
                          <option value="4"> Shopping & services</option>
                          <option value="5"> Music</option>
                          <option value="6"> Social Networking</option>
                          <option value="7"> Browser</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="select3" name="phoneusescategories">
                          <option value="" selected="selected">top-3 use </option>
                          <option value="1"> Games</option>
                          <option value="2"> Productivity</option>
                          <option value="3"> News</option>
                          <option value="4"> Shopping & services</option>
                          <option value="5"> Music</option>
                          <option value="6"> Social Networking</option>
                          <option value="7"> Browser</option>
                        </select>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
  $("select").change(function() {   
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', true);
  }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sakura1/xzjdsusz/

Comment: easier to get help  to post your code and make demo in www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: You can actually embedded a code snippet in the edittor now, and that code snippet can be run from the page that the question is on if you don't feel like using jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

you might want to use **[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead of attr() if you want to enable and disable the options of your select..

**HERE:** **[(jsFiddle DEMO)](http://jsfiddle.net/cuteporing/f3zp7yb4/)**

I added this line just in case you want to remove other disabled options whenever you select a new option

```
$('select option').prop("disabled", false);
```

**CODE SNIPPET :**

```js
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('select option').prop("disabled", false);
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val() + "]").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" name="phoneusescategories">
                      <option value="" selected="selected">top-1 use </option>
                      <option value="Games"> Games</option>
                      <option value="2"> Productivity</option>
                      <option value="3"> News</option>
                      <option value="4"> Shopping & services</option>
                      <option value="5"> Music</option>
                      <option value="6"> Social Networking</option>
                      <option value="7"> Browser</option>
                    </select>

                    <select id="select2" name="phoneusescategories">
                      <option value="" selected="selected">top-2 use </option>
                      <option value="Games"> Games</option>
                      <option value="2"> Productivity</option>
                      <option value="3"> News</option>
                      <option value="4"> Shopping & services</option>
                      <option value="5"> Music</option>
                      <option value="6"> Social Networking</option>
                      <option value="7"> Browser</option>
                    </select>

                    <select id="select3" name="phoneusescategories">
                      <option value="" selected="selected">top-3 use </option>
                      <option value="Games"> Games</option>
                      <option value="2"> Productivity</option>
                      <option value="3"> News</option>
                      <option value="4"> Shopping & services</option>
                      <option value="5"> Music</option>
                      <option value="6"> Social Networking</option>
                      <option value="7"> Browser</option>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK this is an updated answer

```
$('#select1,#select2,#select3').on('change', function(){
         var value =$.trim($(this).val());
    $('select option:contains("'+value+'")').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

[New DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vgfLstgp/1/)
it will work for just Games
So change your option value same of option text like so

```
<option value="Games"> Games</option>
```

Comment: But If i change my selection  again evrythng is disabled eventually i have select input all over my forms and my code is effecting all selects. Is there anyway i can use id's of select in jquery its not working for me.

Comment: Thank u, but third box doesnot disables the games item. did u hav the same thing or am i dng something wrong? when i change selection in second box third box doesnt disable secondbox selected item

Comment: Nope it disabled all Games items in 3 dropdown.. see new demo

Comment: can you show if this works in a table where there are other dropdowns, in the same col? yours is hardcoded with ID, I would need to find other ddl values

Comment: Regard above post could you pls help me : https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/brn47n/how_to_create_dependent_dropdown_list/